# 2 questions about the functions in the `deepnet` Deep Neural Network package in R

Tags: r, neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm using R to perform the Deep Neural Network. But there are so many packages and functions related to neural networks that I am confused.

I am wondering about the following two things.

1. What are the differences between `dbn.dnn.train` and `sae.dnn.train` in the `deepnet` package?
2. What DNN function can control L1 (Lasso penalty) and L2 (Ridge penalty)?

Answer (score 0):

1. The differences are probably best described in the R document(s) for the package(s).
2. I haven't used the packages, but intuitively it may not be so great that regularization methods are controlled externally with some parameters. Many lines of codes must be written for the computation process of pack propagation for it. L1 and L2 regularization methods are two methods to penalize large weights by adding lambda * (absolute values) or 0.5 * lambda * (squares of absolute values) in the cost(error) function. After adding either of the regularization terms, the new dE/dW is easy to compute: just the original dE/dW,  plus lambda * (signs of W (each of which is 1 or -1)) or lambda * (W)

Comment: Thank you, But in my no.1 question, I read the document but, I can't understand. So I posted this question in Crossvalidated. I'm wondering difference of theory between dbn.dnn.train and sae.dnn.train

Comment: I read it just now. sae refers to Stacked AutoEncoder in the document, and dbn Deep neural network in the document. So sae.dnn.train is clear; search tutorials online for stacked auto-encoders. And 'dbn.dnn.train's functionality is a bit unclear; it may be 'Restricted Boltzmann Machine', because I find 'hidden_dropout' and 'visible_dropout' arguments.